# JVC labeling typefaces

Tags: font-identification, typefaces

I've tried using WhatTheFont and other tools, but nothing clear has come through.

What are the typefaces used for labeling in the late-1970s on hi-fi devices such as the JA-S77?

[image: JVC JA-S77]

[image: JVC JA-S77 VU metres top]

[image: JA-S44]

Comment: Can you get a clearer image?

Comment: @Cai, I can try, but all of the large images are sufficiently lo-res to be effectively useless.

Comment: the "ja-s77 stereo etc" is not Futura BTW. My first thought is optima, but I think there are differences (the 7s especially)

Comment: @Yorik, agreed. It is clearly a different face than the labelling

Answer (score 6):

It's hard to say anything with much certainty from that image (or any I can find), but it looks a lot like [Futura](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futura_(typeface)).

[image]

The shape of the "A", "B", "N" and "M"s especially give it away. And you can see by overlaying the same text in Futura (I've done some slight distortion to match the angle of the image but no kerning/spacing on the type itself) that the proportions are pretty much spot on:

[image]

It's not an uncommon use of Futura; You can see this flight control unit that uses Futura for example (which according to Wikipedia "is widespread in the aerospace industry for flight instrument and control markings"):

[image]

Comment: Definately Futura. I was about to post that when your answer popped in. "Trebuchet MS" is a very similar font that the OP may already have. It is narrower, so the OP might scale it horizontally by ~120% to get a reasonable facsimile.

Comment: @Yorik, I'm pretty sure that I have at least a couple of weights of Futura and I've got a pretty sizeable collection of Avenir, assuming Frutiger kept similar enough letter forms (considering that the latter is descended from the former)

Comment: Cai, provided a scale, do you think you could figure the type height (TrueType points)? The height is 158mm and the width is 450mm

Comment: @NoahM type size of the labels I compared earlier is 9pt, the smaller labels (ON/OFF etc) are 7pt.

Comment: Cai, which weight of Futura did you check this against?

Comment: @Cai, when I printed out some things to prepare for making some decals to replace the labeling, those type sizes weren't right

Answer (score 0):

"STEREO INTEGRATED AMPLIFIER" is a "stressed" or "modulated" sans-serif: one with stroke modulation. (In other words, not monoline like most sans-serifs like Helvetica.) This style was very popular in the 1970s, but fell out of fashion soon after - so it's not certain that this font is digitised. [Britannic Light](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/urw/britannic/) is sort of similar, but too condensed. You might have to look around on MyFonts for something using those keywords. The Rolls-Royce (quality and price) recent family in this style is Paul Barnes' [Chiswick Sans](https://commercialtype.com/catalog/chiswick_sans).